# unable to initialize array in c | warning: conversion to long unsigned from long

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, overflow, memset

I'm trying to write a program which starts by creating a 2D array that will represent a graph (note that the dimensions of the graph will be given as input).

I want to initialize this array at 0 and after googling it I found out that you have to do it with memset(), cause the memory for the array will be dynamically allocated from the input file.

Below is a small part of my program so far:

```
long int N;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int i;

    FILE * txt;
    txt = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (txt == NULL) {
        printf("There was an error trying to open the file.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fscanf(txt, "%li", &N);

    long int graph[N][N];
    memset(graph, 0, N*N*sizeof(long int));

    return 1;
}
```

When I'm compiling it with gcc -Wconversion i'm getting the following warning:

> warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘long int’ may change
>   the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]          memset(graph, 0,
>   N*N *sizeof(long int));

I can't understand at which point of the code the compiler is trying to convert a long int to an unsigned one. I searched it and people had the same problem only when they had variables of different types mixed.

Any help would be appreciated!

---EDIT---

With the [help of 'Vlad from Moscow'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59918638/12785539) I was able to solve the above warning (I had to change N to size_t type in order to call memset() correctly), but now I want to initialize another long int array to LONG_MAX and I get a different one:

```
memset(dist, LONG_MAX, N*sizeof(long int));
```

> warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `memset` expects the third argument of the type `size_t`.
So declare the variable N as

```
size_t N;
```

and write

```
fscanf(txt, "%zu", &N);
```

The second warning is related to the second argument of the call of `memset`

```
memset(dist, LONG_MAX, N*sizeof(long int));
```

that expects it of the type `int` that is internally within the function is converted to the type `unsigned char`.

Here is the function declaration.

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

Usually the only applying of the function is to zero-initialize an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any ideas for the new one I edited? :)

Comment: @Vlad What about `memset(graph, 0, sizeof(long int)*N*N);` instead of `memset(graph, 0, N*N*sizeof(long int));`?

Comment: @Vlad so what i'm trying to do cannot be done with memset()?
wanted to use it for faster execution but i guess i will go for the "old-fashioned for" way instead...

Comment: @DonS Yes, it can not be done with memset for a signed int type

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Wouldn´t size_t math solve it too with `memset(graph, 0, sizeof(long int)*N*N)`?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica LONG_MAX is a standard macro. It shall not be redefined.:)

Comment: Well, the OP did not provided the entired source code, so I can not be sure if he means the standard macro inside of `limits.h` or some of his own ones.

Answer (score 0):

size_t may interpreted as unsigned int or as unsigned long int; depends on machine.

There is no need to use memset() for fill the array with 0s, you can give this stuff to compiler.
Simply assign 0 to first element and compiler will assign 0 to all uninitialized elements!

```
long int graph[N][N] = {0};
```

You are trying to use memset() in wrong place!
memset() sets the storage in 'bytewise manner'.

> void *memset(s,c,n) --> place character c into first n characters of
>   s, return s

notice that c is a character not an integer.

> So, how to initialize an array with LONG_MAX ?

Using a loop:

```
 for(long i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   dist[i] = LONG_MAX;
```